# Problema libreria html2pdf con servidor web

Tags: php

alguien de ustedes a tenido problemas con servidores al implementar la libreria **html2pdf**

En localhost funciona perfectamente, pero al momento de subir en el servidor no funciona alguien me podria orientar

anexo lo siguiente

```
  <?php
  require_once "funciones.php";
  $link = Conectarse();
  $idform = $_GET['idform'];
  $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM formato WHERE id = '%s'",$idform);
  $formato = $link->query($sql);
  $formato = mysqli_fetch_assoc($formato);
  $mes = array("01"=>"ENERO", "02"=>"FEBRERO", "03"=>"MARZO", "04"=>"ABRIL", "05"=>"MAYO", "06"=>"JUNIO", "07"=>"JULIO", "08"=>"AGOSTO", "09"=>"SEPTIEMBRE", "10"=>"OCTUBRE", "11"=>"NOVIEMBRE", "12"=>"DICIEMBRE");
  $sql1 = "SELECT nombre FROM cog where id ='".$formato['id_cog']."'";
  $result = $link->query($sql1);
  $desc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  #Contenido x
  $sql2 = "SELECT nombre,director FROM oficinas where  id ='".$formato['id_oficina']."'";
  $result1=$link->query($sql2);
  $datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
    require_once('/pdf/html2pdfclass.php');
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','es','UTF-8');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output('factura_comprometido.pdf');
?>
```

**Agradezco sus recomendaciones o si alguien conoce alguna librería que funcione mejor **

Comment: Hola harriroot, que problema tiene, ¿genera algun error? se impirme en blanco, solo mencionas que no funciona, pero ¿que comportamiento tiene?

Comment: Hola, seria ideal si puedes colocar, Que no esta funcionando correctamente? Que error te arroja cuando lo pruebas desde el servidor publicado??? Vez algo en la consola???

Comment: Hola,jasilva y Wilfredo gracias por responder me genera un error interno en el servidor **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: Tienes acceso a los logs de apache??, si tienes acceso revísalos y sube el error para tener una mejor descripción del problema.

Comment: Mientras contestas a los comentarios de juan1992 y WilfredoP, te diría una cosa: **el código de arriba puede sufrir ataques de inyección de SQL**. El uso de funciones `mysqli_*` es un buen paso, pero no es suficiente; tienes que usar consultas preparadas/parametrizadas (`sprintf` no es suficiente tampoco).

Comment: Gracias amigo si lo tendré en cuenta

Comment: esto es lo bonito de la industria en la que estamos: la clave para que todos crezcamos es compartir conocimiento de buena manera, algo que raras veces se ve en otras industrias. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias amigo :) Por todo saludos y bendiciones

Comment: Utilizas una ruta absoluta (no relativa) en la línea `/pdf/...`. ¿Realmente está la biblioteca html2pdfclass.php en la raíz de la unidad?

Answer (score 1):

Algo me dice que el error podría estar aquí:

```
require_once "funciones.php";
require_once('/pdf/html2pdfclass.php');
```

Revisa si el archivo funciones.php o html2pdfclass.php están siendo llamados en la ruta que especificas.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias fredyfx ya lo revisamos y siguie sin funcionar y esta bien la ruta

Comment: de nada, acabo de darme cuenta de algo  $formato = $link->query($sql);
  $formato = mysqli_fetch_assoc($formato);
ambos tienen el mismo nombre de las variables, no debería ser el 2do formato tener un nombre diferente?

Comment: Gracias amigo, si un error de dedo

Comment: de nada amigo, entonces pregunta resuelta?

Comment: no realmente fredyfx dado que la librería no la pude implementar, mi alternativa fue mandar una pagina html a cecas, lo dejare asi se visualiza igual con un ctrl +p para imprirmir.

Comment: a ver mi estimado @harriroot, si por el lado del server hay problemas, vamos jugando por el lado del cliente! quizás sea lo que buscas:  https://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/ buena suerte y éxitos con el desarrollo!